# mdadm raid1 back to single drive

Tags: raid, software-raid, mdadm

I have a raid1 install of debian 7 with software mdadm on 2 disks.

What I want here is to split this to 2 separate systems and be able to multiboot them.

I guess while I have the system running from the first drive I could do:

mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb1 --remove /dev/sdb1

This would cause sdb1 to be removed from the array (and won't be resynched even after reboot). Then remove the first drive and do:

mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sda1 --remove /dev/sda1

on the second while it is booted. Is this enough or I have to zero out raid superblocks as well? I don't want that the replication from any of the 2 systems start up all the sudden killing the other disk.

Thanks